# Notepad++:: Completely remove lines that contains question mark via Regex

Tags: regex, string, text, replace, notepad++

Well, I guess that that is my title is pretty much self explanatory on what I'm about to achieve.

Here is an example of my current text file:

```
"Diva" was the winning song of the Eurovision Song Contest 1998.
Who will win Eurovision Song Contest 2015?
Eurovision Song Contest Statistics:
Who will win Eurovision 2015?
```

This is what I want to get:

```
"Diva" was the winning song of the Eurovision Song Contest 1998.
Eurovision Song Contest Statistics:
```

So basically each line that contains the `?` character (the location doesn't necessarily have to be at the end of the line) will be replaced with nothing.

I have tried `[^\r\n]*?[^\r\n]*([\r\n]+|$)` but it removes too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^[^\n]*\?[^\n]*(?:\n|$)
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/76

Answer (score 3):

In order to deal with any linebreak:

Find what: `^.*\?.*(\R|$)`
Replace with: `<NOTHING>`

`\R` stands for any line break, ie. `\r`, `\n` and `\r\n`

Make sure that `Regular Expression` is checked and `dot matches newline` is NOT.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[^\r\n]*\?[^\r\n]*([\r\n]+|$)` regex to match a line having a `?` symbol. Mark `. matches newline`.

Replace with empty string.

[image]

Comment: Opps... This was exactly what I was doing I just forgot the backslash \?

Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @Hezi-Gangina: You are welcome. `?` is a special character in regexes, and must be escaped when you search for a literal `?`. Just in case you are interested, here is some more information on what needs to be escaped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions.

Comment: I also added to the question that detail that you tried a regex with unescaped question mark. It's important.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid regular expressions and use the **Mark** tab of the **Find** window. Select **Search mode** as **Normal**, also select **Bookmark line**. Set the **Find what** to be `?` and then click **Mark all**. Next use the menu => **Search** => **Bookmarks** => **Remove bookmarked lines**.