# how extract the string containing underscore in notepad++

Tags: string, notepad++

I have to extract only those string that contains underscore in notepad++. My file is like

```
T-cell_stimulation
transcription_factor
NF-kappa_B
kappa_B_site
HIV-1_long_terminal_repeat
HIV-1
HIV-2_enhancer
HIV-2
monocyte
T_cell
cis-acting_element
kappa_B_site
purine-rich_binding_site
```

and my desired output is

```
T-cell_stimulation
transcription_factor
NF-kappa_B
kappa_B_site
HIV-1_long_terminal_repeat
HIV-2_enhancer
T_cell
cis-acting_element
kappa_B_site
purine-rich_binding_site
```

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537982/notepad-completely-remove-lines-that-contains-question-mark-via-regex/29543486#29543486 . but modify the method by searching for `_` and at the finish use **Remove unmarked lines**.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Notepad++'s [regex](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) search.

something like the following:

```
.*_.*
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem through code in python
 code is

```
import re;
file = "C:/Python26/test.txt";
f=open("rzlt.txt",'w')
pattern ='\w+_\w+[_\w+]*|\w+-\w+[-\w+]*';
with open(file,'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines();
    c=0;
    for word in lines:
        if re.match(pattern, word):
            f.write( word)
            c=c+1;
    print c;
f.close();
```